# Symfony2: How to operate with datetime-objects

Tags: datetime, symfony

i can't really get it how to work with datetime-objects in symfony2.

i have few games-entries in database which one has a datetime-property.
and now i want to compare to the actual date: i want to have all records from the past 10 days. how can i achieve this?

i tried this

```
date($game->getZeit(), mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d'),date('y')))
```

to get a compareable date which i can compare with

```
date('Y.m.d H:i:s', mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d'),date('y')));
```

but that didnt work because

```
$game->getZeit()
```

cannot be converted to a string. why? so how can i debug this one? how can i know its value? how can i compare it with other datetimes or date-strings?

quick help would be really appreciated! :)

kind regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Symfony2 (Doctrine ORM) dates represented as DateTime objects (http://php.net/DateTime)
So if `$game->getZeit()` is instance of [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), you can convert it to string like

```
$game->getZeit()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give another example.

In my case my retrieved data was

```
array(3) {
  ["full_name"]=>
  string(13) "Administrator"
  ["current_location"]=>
  string(8) "Orogenic"
  ["location_updatedAt"]=>
  object(DateTime)#682 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2019-09-12 08:21:03.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
}
```

To get the location_updatedAt value you can use,

```
$boxInfo['warehouseLocationUpdatedAt']->format('Y-m-d')
```